# Python Tkinter Entry.get() function, how do I get 0 if I have no input?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a restaurant program using Python tkinter, I designed to use entry function to get the number of order. I put 10 different meals, and 10 entry spaces, but when I run this program, it shows error since I only entered amount for the first meal. How do I set no entry as number 0 instead of null/none.
Thanks so much!

Comment: self.entry1.get()

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def get_entry_value(entrybox):
    if entrybox.get() == None:
        return 0
    return entrybox.get()
```

hopefully, you can just call the function instead of using entrybox.get(), and if the value of the entry widget is null then it will return 0.